# Characterization of alpha-equivalence in languages with bindings

Tags: logic, lambda-calculus, first-order-logic, variable-binding

Following up on [this post](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/76616/algorithm-for-deciding-alpha-equivalence-of-terms-in-languages-with-bindings) denoting $(x \leftrightarrow y)$ the permutation of $x$ and $y$ and $P[x \leftrightarrow y]$ the term obtained from the term $P$ by permuting $x$ and $y$ (so for example if $P = \lambda x. \lambda y. x y$ then we have $P[x \leftrightarrow y] = \lambda y. \lambda x. y x$)  (note that such transformation is immune from potential variable capture unlike those based on substitutions $y \leftarrow x$ or $x \leftarrow y$), then it appears to me that when $x \ne y$, a term $\lambda x. P$ is alpha equivalent to a term $\lambda y. Q$ if and only if $y$ is not free in $P$ and $Q$ is alpha equivalent to $P[y \leftrightarrow x]$. I find this observation interesting because it lends itself to a simple recursion in order to establish alpha-equivalence (as opposed to using an algorithm based on de Bruijn indices). I would like to know whether anyone thinks this observation is wrong, or whether it is true (a proof sketch or counterexample is welcome), or whether while true, it is not very interesting because the complexity of the recursive computation would be worse than a solution based on de Bruijn indices (each step requires determining whether $y$ is free in $P$ and permuting variable $x$ and $y$ in $P[x \leftrightarrow y]$).

Comment: I'm sorry, I'd misread your question. I don't have time to write a proper answer now, but in a nutshell, yes, the property is correct; it's the key fact in proving that the definition of alpha equivalence using capture-avoiding substitution and the definition of alpha equivalence using permutations. Implementations of alpha equivalence often work that way, but you still have the burden of doing renamings, and they can be costly because you aren't ever skipping terms protected by binders.

Comment: @Gilles I am very grateful for your time, thank you!

Comment: May I ask what you're after? Alpha equivalence has been beaten to death.

Comment: @AndrejBauer I wanted to have confirmation that the property I have indicated was true, with possibly some insight about it which Gilles has given me.

Comment: That is perfectly all right. I just wanted to point out that you shouldn't waste time reinventing alpha equivalence if you're really after something larger. It's better to just reuse what is known.

Comment: You may be interested in looking at the various "nominal" systems. Small surveys are given on the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominal_terms_(computer_science)) and the [nLab page](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/nominal+set), though there's quite a lot more work than indicated there. I'm mostly referring mostly to the references in each of those. Implementations tend to have names like [FreshFoo](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~amp12/research/freshml/index.html) or [αBar](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/jcheney/programs/aprolog/).

Comment: @AndrejBauer I apologize and am grateful for the advice. I am not a pro. So there are many things I don't know (and hence cannot reuse). I am trying to get better at this, read more and not re-invent the wheel. But there are things I think I know while not being completely sure, so I take the liberty to ask.

Comment: @DerekElkins Thank you Derek I will look at these references carefully

Comment: I see. Well, if you're learning then reinventing the wheel is not a bad to go about it. If you're thinking of implementing things, then just keep in mind that alpha equivalence is almost always completely avoided in favor of a mechanism such as de Bruijn indices.

Comment: @AndrejBauer Thank you very much, I will definitely study de Bruijn indices now.